# Creating data type for variable representation, represented by all letters a..z, lowercase or uppercase

Tags: haskell, types

I want to make a data type Var which represents a variable. A variable is a character that is a, b, c... z, lowercase or uppercase.

I can write this:

```
data Var = A | B | C -- continues to Z
```

but I can't write this:

```
data Var = a | b | c -- continues to z
```

Presumably because they are lowercase. Is there an elegant way to make this data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to simply have

```
data Var = Var Char
```

While `Var 'c'` and `Var 'D'` will populate the type as desired, unfortunately `Var '%'` can populate it as well. There are two ways to fix this. One is to enumerate all constructors as you did:

```
data Var = A | B | C -- continues to Z
         | SmallA | SmallB | SmallC -- continues to z
```

The other way to only let correct values get into the type is to use [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors).

Comment: Forgot to accept this answer way back.  Yes, smart constructors would have probably been the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't - as you said, they have to be uppercase.

I'd go with

```
data Var = Var_A | Var_B | ... | Var_Z 
         | Var_a | Var_b | ... | Var_z
```

or `V_A | V_B` etc.

An alternative is to use

```
newtype Var = Var Char
```

but that loses some safety, but is really handing for reading and showing. You'd have to make sure in your code that no invalid `Char`s end up as `Var`s.

(`data Var_A | ...` is a lot of boilerplate code, so you could do just A to D, and write the code just working with those letters, then set yourself a little exercise to write a Haskell program to write the source code of the data type and the parsing function for you! You'll learn a bit about String manipulation in Haskell by doing so.)

*((There's such a thing as Template Haskell that's designed to do the boilerplate job for you, but it's rather advanced and you should learn your string manipulation first. Also, while I'm on the topic, once you really know what you're doing, look into Scrap Your Boilerplate, which is a bunch of very advanced techniques for writing good, clever code. You need a lot more Haskell experience before you get to that though.))*